# How to map array of numbers to property inside a mapping table using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, deserialization, automapper, json-deserialization, dto

In my project I have:

StartUp.cs

```
var carDtos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<CarDto>>(inputJson);
var cars = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Car>>(carDtos);
```

Here I deserialize the JSON file using the DTO model, then try to map those models to the Car class. I get the error - *Error mapping types.*

Car.cs

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Make { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }

    public long TravelledDistance { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Sale> Sales { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PartCar> PartCars { get; set; } = new List<PartCar>();
}
```

CarDto.cs

```
public class CarDto
{
    public string Make { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }

    public long TravelledDistance { get; set; }

    public ICollection<int> PartsId { get; set; }
}
```

cars.json

```
[ 
 {
     "make": "Opel",
     "model": "Astra",
     "travelledDistance": 516628215,
     "partsId": [
         39,
         62,
         72
     ]
 },
 {
     "make": "Opel",
     "model": "Astra",
     "travelledDistance": 156191509,
     "partsId": [
         48,
         44,
         112
     ]
 }
]
```

CarDealerProfile.cs

```
public class CarDealerProfile : Profile
{
    public CarDealerProfile()
    {          
        this.CreateMap<Car, CarDto>()
            .ForMember(dest =>
                dest.PartsId,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PartCars));
    }
}
```

I know the code doesn't work because I am not mapping properly, but I just cant figure it out.

I want to map the numbers from the JSON array named *partsId*, through the mapping table *PartCars* located in the *Car* class and save those numbers as *Ids* for the *Part* class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Profile` you defined mapping from `Car` to `CarDto` but in your code you are trying to map from `CarDto` to `Car`. To be able to map both directions add `ReverseMap()`. Also you need to tell automapper how to convert `int` to `PartCar` and `PartCar` to `int` so it can map `ICollection<PartCar> PartCars` property to `ICollection<int> PartsId` property and vice versa. Try this:

```
public class CarDealerProfile : Profile
{
    public CarDealerProfile()
    {          
        CreateMap<Car, CarDto>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.PartsId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PartCars))
           .ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<PartCar, int>().ConvertUsing(o => o.PartId);
        CreateMap<int, PartCar>().ConvertUsing(o => new PartCar { PartId = o });           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `provide a mapping from CarDto to Car`.The mapping currently defined is from Car to CarDto.

Comment: Tried reversing them but still not working, even used .ReverseMap(). I think the problem is how to tell it to map the array.

Comment: @FadoBagi : You need to use `ConvertUsing` and specify the mapping. See the answer given by @Dimitris Maragkos. That has the code sample.